# Mouse sensitivity settings keeps resetting after suspending/rebooting because of different Desktop Environments

Tags: gnome, mouse, xfce

I have Unity and XFCE and after an system upgrade my mouse sensitivity keeps resetting to the one on Unity where you can't turn off the acceleration. I have used the `xinput --set-prop 12 'libinput Accel Profile Enabled' 0, 1` command but it doesn't keep the settings. I have also added those settings in `~/.profile` but the settings keep resetting. I didn't have this issue before so I suspect that it was because of something that I have upgraded.

It might be because of the fact that I have a hybrid wireless/wired mouse where the system reads it as 3 different devices (I don't know why but when it's wired `xinput` lists it as 2 devices), a wired one and a wireless one.

I tried locking the XFCE mouse settings file to read-only and it didn't work. After resuming my mouse would reset to the old settings with acceleration on. After changing the `~/.profile` file my XFCE mouse settings sensitivity/acceleration bar would stay, but the sensitivity would still reset unless I did a `xinput --set-prop 12 'libinput Accel Profile Enabled' 0, 1`.

I'm pretty sure that it's a problem with gnome settings autostarting but I don't know which one to disable and I have a few settings that I want to keep.

**EDIT** : turns out that I didn't reboot after reinstalling `xserver-xorg-input-libinput`

Comment: You'll want to make your start up "DE-aware" and reset mouse automatically.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix What do you mean? A bash script?

Comment: Yes. Lot s of people around here enjoy writing them. You just provide the terminal commands you use.